# JavaScript to assign colors to all web-parts on a page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

Would like to define a JavaScript function that I can pass in some colors and it will use those colors to set the web-part headers to those colors.

Pseudo code would be to loop through my web-parts (only those with visible headers) and ignore those that have no visible header.  Each visible header will be assigned to the next color in the array of colors that was provided as a parameter.

If two colors were passed, then the first visible web-part header would use color1, the second visible web-part header, color2, the third would use color1, 
 and so on ..

`$('#WebPartWPQ6_ChromeTitle').css('background-color', 'red')`;

I would expect the implementation to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-Color="red, blue, black" src="../SiteAssets/js-enterprise/ColorHeaders.js"></script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you already worked out the logic in your psuedo code and description above, why not code it? Or are you posting a homework assignment?

Comment: The given terms `headers` and `webparts` are either unclear or misused and you probably mean sth else. I never heard of webparts and an htm header is sth one does not see in any case.. Are you able to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Web-parts are the components you add to a SharePoint page.  They have a naming convention WebPartWPQ# where # is a sequence number of the web-part.  My ignorance is not knowing what a homework assignment is.  Yes, I'm asking someone if they have done this before or could they now do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var colors=["red","blue","black"];
    $(".ms-webpart-chrome-title").each(function(i){     
        $(this).css('background-color',colors[i%colors.length]);
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect!  Thank you

Comment: If I wanted to change the text color, I had thought that I just needed to add the following line, but it did not work?    $(this).css('color',textcolor);  What would I have to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  $(".ms-webpart-titleText > a").each(function(i){     
        $(this).css('color',textcolor);
    });

Comment: @SteveHarvancik There are two problems with this answer, 1. It isn't a function as you requested, it is just declaring an array on `DocumentReady` and then adding colors. 2. You said in your post that you only wanted to add color to "visible" headers, this answer adds color to every header regardless of `visiblity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addColor(colorArray){
    //Check if parameter is an array and has elements, if not throw exception
    if(!Array.isArray(colorArray) || colorArray.length === 0){
        throw "Parameter is not an array or empty!";
    }
    //Declare local count for moving through the array
    let count = 0;
    //Select all elements which are of type header, this uses a common class "header"
    //Use Array.forEach to iterate the collection of elements
    document.querySelectorAll('.ms-webpart-chrome-title').forEach(function(el){
        //Check visibility
        if(el.offsetWidth > 0 && el.offsetHeight > 0){
           //Set backgroundColor to current color of array
           el.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[count];
           //Move to next element in array or back to beginning
           count = count + 1 >= colorArray.length ? 0 : count + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like it might work for standard HTML, but not for SharePoint 2013 on-prem.  You need to find all the web-parts headers that have an id of WebpartWPQ#_ChromeTitle where # is a number.                            Example: <div class="ms-webpart-chrome-title" id="WebPartWPQ4_ChromeTitle">
  <span title="Content Editor - Retrieve Web Details - Allows authors to enter rich text content." id="WebPartTitleWPQ4" class="js-webpart-titleCell"><h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-webpart-titleText" ...
 </div>

Comment: @SteveHarvancik This uses plain javascript so no dependency on JQuery is necessary. I only used '.header' as an example as you hadn't provided the className in your post originally. I updated my answer to reflect the desired className in the selector. Not to mention the accepted answer didn't form this as a function, which I did in my answer. "Would like to define a JavaScript function"